# Outlook reminder for everyone in group

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, calendar

At the office we use Office 365 services and have Outlook as our email client. I would like to find a way to have everyone on my team add some kind of shared calendar which would enable group reminders to pop up whenever I schedule them.

Now I have looked at every solution and article I could find, and as far as I can tell, it's impossible for reminders to work unless you actually add an Outlook account (with mailbox, calendar, tasks, etc) or invite someone to a meeting.

What I'm looking for is more of a solution like a public folder calendar, where a user can just add it to Outlook one time and then I can manage the reminders that will pop up for them. I'm hoping you fine folks can suggest something I haven't discovered...

Thank you in advance!

**TL;DR** How do I get a meeting reminder to pop up on group members' Outlook calendar without actually adding any individual to the meeting request?

Comment: Create a group from Office365. An email address will be associated with the group. Add every member of your team to that group. Try to manage the reminders via the group calendar.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I tried that and unfortunately the reminders do not work, even though the users have the calendar automatically added to their Outlook

Comment: See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/reminders-from-shared-calendars/6a2f8fb9-ffc9-488a-b093-d5619f612925

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio this is what I'm trying to avoid: "you can add different users or groups to attendees section" because simply adding the user to the group and creating an appointment on the group calendar will not display a reminder. You must add the person as an attendee of the appointment/meeting for the reminder to work.

Comment: If a user is subscribed to an Office 365 group, he should get the reminders.

Comment: @harrymc please test this and you'll see that is not the case

Answer (score 0):

Agree with  Reddy, according to my tests, creating a distribution group and adding everyone to this distribution group, when creating a Outlook meeting and add this group as the recipient, everyone in the group should be able to receive meeting reminders normally. If the problem still exists, please check if there is something wrong with your Outlook client feature, you could try to repair your Outlook client and see if this issue could be resolved.

Comment: How is this different from just sending a meeting invite to people? The whole point is I'm trying to avoid having to add individuals to the meeting. If I create a distribution group, send the invite, and then someone new joins the group, they won't get that reminder. I'd have to manually forward it to them. This is what I'm trying to avoid.